# Would active connections cause this UFW Block?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 as a gateway, routing is controlled by iptables.

I'm getting a number of strange blocks in UFW which seem to effect established connections. Is there any way this block would effect established connections or a website loading/video streaming?

```
Jan 12 21:15:39 ukxn kernel: [126249.931956] [UFW BLOCKaa] IN=eth0
OUT= MAC=04:01:88:e6:06:01:84:b5:9c:f9:f8:30:08:00 SRC=31.13.93.7
DST=178.0.0.120 LEN=88 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=86 ID=53926 DF PROTO=TCP
SPT=443 DPT=51722 WINDOW=16080 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Thanks

Comment: We need the context of your overall iptables rule set to be able to answer (and maybe not even then). Please edit your question adding the outputs of `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`. However, be aware that some (like me) are not fond of looking at UFW generated iptables rule sets.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, **yes**.

What that log message is telling me is that packets from source `31.13.93.7:443` (or https://facebook.com) are being blocked, likely in your `FORWARD` chain if the connection is originating from your LAN and not your Ubuntu gateway. If the connection is originating from your Ubuntu gateway, the block will likely be in your `INPUT` chain.

I concur with Doug Smythies. Please edit your post to contain the output of the command `iptables -vnL` in order for us to better understand your scenario.